# Sheet presentation disables NSMagnificationGestureRecognizer

Tags: macos, appkit

So I have a view with attached Pan and Magnify gesture recognisers in a view controller.

When I present the view controller using the Show, Modal or Presentation segues, both gesture recognisers work fine. But when I present it as a Sheet, only the Pan recogniser responds to input. The Magnify recogniser simply doesn't fire at all.

[Sample project here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/94446538/SheetGestures.zip). Use the buttons in the first window to show the view controller in different methods, and gesture anywhere in the presented view. The indicators will show which gestures have been recognised.